# Update state variable within Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-state

I'm currently working on a React site, and I have a custom `HeaderBar` component, and I would like to display the current page title on it. I had planned to just update a state variable from the Router to change the title. However, understandably, this results in a "too many re-renders" error.

Here's my current code:

```
function App() {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("")

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <HeaderBar siteTitle="My Website Name" pageTitle={pageTitle} />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            {setPageTitle("Login")}
            <h1>Login Page</h1>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/main">
            {setPageTitle("Main")}
            <h1>Main Page</h1>
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/about">
            {setPageTitle("About")}
            <h1>About Page</h1>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Obviously I could just move the `HeaderBar` declaration inside each of the Routes, but this seems like a hackish solution to me.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: create layout component and in routes pass component title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling functions inside JSX, these functions are executed on every render, which would results on the 3 `setPageTitle` calls being executed on every render (although in your case, only the first `setPageTitle` is going to be called thus resulting in the too many updates as it would be cycling between calling the first `setPageTitle`, updating the state, rendering again, and calling it once again).

Ideally, if you define components for each route, you would need to call `setPageTitle` outside of the return statement (meaning outside of the JSX, before rendering), which would result in the `setPageTitle` being called only when you access the corresponding route.

In order to do that without defining components for your routes, you could do the following:

```
function App() {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("")

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <HeaderBar siteTitle="My Website Name" pageTitle={pageTitle} />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" render={() => {
            setPageTitle("Login");
            return (<h1>Login Page</h1>);
          }}>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/main" render={() => {
            setPageTitle("Main");
            return (<h1>Main Page</h1>);
          }}>
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/about" render={() => {
            setPageTitle("About");
            return (<h1>About Page</h1>);
          }}>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah very clever solution! Thank you!